# How to use jQuery i18n plugin on fiddle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

I Googled a lot but able to find how to use i18n plugin on fiddle. Actually I am thinking to do so like like that

1. Create 3 json files English, French, Spanish
2. Include that file in my html my file
3. In all three json files my key is same example ("name").
4. I want to show name value different on different language .

Can we do this using i18n plugin on fiddle ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To include extra resources in *JSFiddle*

1. Go to your fiddle's edit/create page on http://jsfiddle.net/
2. Look for `External Resources` on the left panel
3. Click it
4. Paste in your plugin's URL
5. Click the `+`

Your fiddle will now include your plugin. Remember you'll need to save for it to persist.

As for whether you can load in your *JSON*, it depends on how you're doing it - you may encounter *same origin* issues. Try including some hard coded dummy *JSON* for testing with a fiddle instead.